# How to covert array to matrix for Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script

Hi I have an array I need to convert into a 2 dimensional array so I can valuesSet the array into a google sheets document.

In essence, I need to convert an array [a,b,c,d,e,f] into a matrix [["a"],["b"],["c"],["d"],["e"],["f"]]. I have tried using a for loop to push [\" + element + \"] around each element. However, I still get an error message when running the script. "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]."

Please help!

```
// function pastValues should past 6 columns each comprised of a,b,c,d,e,f. Each letter is in its own cell.
function pasteValues() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
  for(var i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
    array = toMatrix(array);
    sheet1.getRange(2, i, 6, 1).setValues(array)
  }

}

// convert array [a,b,c,d,e,f] into matrix [[a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f]] so it can be set into newShceduleSheet.
function toMatrix(arr){
var newMatrix = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  newMatrix.push("[\"" + arr[i] + "\"]");
  }
  return newMatrix;
}
```

Comment: I can see several ways to go with this, depending on what you're looking for - it might be helpful to share what you'd like the Google Sheet output to look like.

Comment: I'd like the google sheet output to be 6 rows. Each item is with its own row and own cell. then 6 columns of this. So each column would read a, b, c, d, e, f. from top to bottom.

Comment: OK, I recommend @Tanaike's 2nd solution ("Other pattern"), with the caveat that the exit condition for the for loop should probably be "i <= 6" and/or both '6' should be array.length, if you're always looking for a square matrix.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In your script, `"[\"" + arr[i] + "\"]"` becomes string.

  - You can use `[arr[i]]`.
- You can put `array = toMatrix(array);` to outside of for loop.

#### Modified script :

```
// function pastValues should past 6 columns each comprised of a,b,c,d,e,f. Each letter is in its own cell.
function pasteValues() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
  array = toMatrix(array);
  for(var i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
    sheet1.getRange(2, i, 6, 1).setValues(array);
  }
}

// convert array [a,b,c,d,e,f] into matrix [[a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f]] so it can be set into newShceduleSheet.
function toMatrix(arr){
  var newMatrix = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    newMatrix.push([arr[i]]);
  }
  return newMatrix;
}
```

#### Other pattern :

You can also convert `array` using `map()`.

```
function pasteValues() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
  array = array.map(function(e){return [e]});
  for(var i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
    sheet1.getRange(2, i, 6, 1).setValues(array);
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify this.

### Edit :

I'm not sure whether this is what you want. If my understanding is correct, how about this? In this sample script, you can use array you want. For example, you can use `["a","b","c"]` and `["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]`. The array is transposed, and inserted from column A. You can set the number of copies at `var n = array.length;`. The default is the length of array.

```
function pasteValues() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
  array = array.map(function(e){return [e]});

  var n = array.length; // Please input the number of columns that you want to copy.
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sheet1.getRange(2, i, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice clean answer for Other pattern; Probably should be i <= array.length or i <=
 6 (started at 1 vs. 0, and also not clear to me if OP wanted a square matrix vs. the row count and column count being equal was coincidence)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion, and now I get an error:  Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 6.       this is for the line of code     sheet1.getRange(2,i,6,1).setValues(array;

Comment: row count and column count were equal as a coincidence

Comment: I see now. I think my problem is that I wanted the function to paste the values into a column. Instead it pastes each iteration into a row. Is there any easy way to resolve this? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Timothy Johns Thank you for your support. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @BAM  I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, no error occurs for both patterns. So I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike the edit looks great to me, works in my environment as well, for various array lengths and values of n.

Comment: @Timothy Johns Thank you so much for your quick response. I'm glad to know that this script works at other account.

Comment: @Tanaike, YES, I have confirmed your solution works! thank you very much.

Comment: @BAM Thank you for your response.